# Objective C - Mac OS X - Simulate a mouse click event onto a specific application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, mouseevent

Hi what I'm trying to do is to simulate a mouse click into an application's window such as finder.

Here is my code so far on how to do a mouse double click event that works. But will only click onto top left screen. Well, assume user clicks finder, finder window opens. I want my code to simulate a click into the center of the application specified.

Code for double-click:

```
CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, CGPointMake(0,0), kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
CGEventSetType(theEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseUp);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);

CGEventSetIntegerValueField(theEvent, kCGMouseEventClickState, 2);

CGEventSetType(theEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseDown);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);

CGEventSetType(theEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseUp);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);

CFRelease(theEvent);
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

To change location of the click , you need to modify this line :

```
CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, CGPointMake(0,0), kCGMouseButtonLeft);
```

to

```
CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, CGPointMake(desiredX,desiredY), kCGMouseButtonLeft);
```

where desiredX, and desiredY are the x and y for the center of your window/application.